# Applications of Matroid Theory in Pure Mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, matroids

I know that matroids are useful in algorithms design. Are there applications of the the general framework of matroid in Pure Mathematics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can find applications in pure mathematics (among other disciplines too) by great mathematicians (like Richard Stanley for example) in this link https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63847/what-are-the-external-triumphs-of-matroid-theory/63853#63853.